# How to have FragmentNavigation#navigate() behavior with FragmentTransaction#add() instead of #replace()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, android-jetpack-navigation

I am working around to preserve the view (without storing as local variable) of fragment and in current Navigation Component it looks certain that `onDestroyView()` is called, I want to avoid calling `onDestroyView()` with Android Navigation but there is no such method that behaves like there was in `FragmentTransaction.add()` in our vanilla Fragment.

In Navigation Jetpack we have:

`FragmentNavigator.navigate()` which makes use of `fragmentTransaction.replace()` like this :

```
ft.replace(mContainerId, frag);
```

Why there is no option of `ft.add()` method?  If there is a workaround, how can we do it?

Is it like the concept of `ft.add()` is being discontinued?

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Why `add` makes sense for you and `replace` doesn't? Navigation library helps you *switch* between destinations. `add` doesn't really fit that description. Perhaps a screenshot would help.

Comment: I want to go from screen A from screen B to get a location, when the fragment B passes back the location to Screen A, the screen A should animate the marker from older position to the new position recently returned from the screen B , doing so with fragment navigation the view of Scren A gets recreated in onCreateView() I want to avoid recreating the view.